# Cygwin + Rails = strange warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

When ever I run a rake command I get the following warning:

> which: no sudo in
>   (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygrdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/.....

it then goes on to list on all of the paths listed in my windows environment paths in a similar fashion after the ellipsis.  Any ideas? Google wasn't very much help.

Comment: Is there any info on which file/line number the error occurs in?

Comment: It's just a warning (not an error) so it continues to run whatever command I issued after it spits that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't have a "sudo" utility. ("sudo" raises privileges to root before running commands.)

You can try creating a "sudo" shell script with the following content.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

"$@"
```

That might work, but it might not. If it doesn't, you might have to log in as "Administrator" before you run "rake". Or change your user type to "Power User". Or change your user type to "Administrator". All three of those changes introduce some security risks.

Comment: How would one make a "Sudo" shell script? Where do you put this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the rake command is trying to run the program `sudo`, which is a Linux-specific program not available for Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use a "sudo" shell script wrapper around "runas". See

[Microsoft documentation for runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)

for details.